# Linear Transformation of Complex Analysis Problems

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the result of linear transformation of the circle $L: |z-1|=1$ by $w = \dfrac{i} {z+2i}$?

I don't have idea how to step up first on this problem. I have read some texts,  but don't found any informations to solve this problems. Do you have any idea? At least giving me step to do.

Comment: Small correction: That's a fractional linear transformation, not a linear transformation.

Comment: What is the word “linear” doing here? Do you believe that your transformation is a linear map?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Invert the transformation, i.e., find $z$ in terms of $w$. Hint: $\pmatrix{0 & i \\ 1 & 2i} \pmatrix{-2i & i \\ 1 & 0} = \pmatrix{i & 0 \\ 0 & i}$.

Step 2: Put this expression for $z$ into $|z-1| = 1$ to get an equation in $w$.

Step 3: Look at this $w$-equation to see what kind of curve it describes.

Comment: I got $(-4+4i)w^2 - 2iw + 3 = 0$ and this is a parabole equation.

Comment: That certainly seems plausible at first blush, but for that to be right, the point at infinity (i.e., $w = \infty$) would have to be on your curve; that corresponds to $z + 2i = 0$ or $z = -2i$, and that's *not* on the original curve. So it looks as if there might be an algebra error somewhere. Let's see how $z = 0$ (which is on the original curve) turns out. That corresponds to $w = \frac{1}{2}$, which, plugged into your equation, gives $-i + 2 = 0$. So there was definitely an algebra error.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange $w=\dfrac{i}{z+2i}$ to get $z=\dfrac{i}{w}-2i$. Substitute into $L$:

$$|\frac{i}{w}-2i-1|=1 \iff |i-(2i+1)w|=|w|$$
Now let $w=x+iy$ and square both sides: this should help you to work out what the transformation does.

Comment: Better still, since we often write $z = x + iy$, you might let $w = u + iv$.